# GWT noserver This module hasn't been compiled yet. Intelijj

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt

I am using gwt 2.8

I am having trouble launching gwt in dev/super dev mode with the option -noserver. I try to use gwt with java 9 but there is an issue using the embedded jetty which doesn't work with java 9.

So I am trying to use my own jetty with the options:

-noserver

-war "path_to_my_jetty/webapps"

Here is the log when I start from Intellij :

```
Running CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel, 1.8, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir, path_to_my_jetty/webapps, -logLevel, INFO, -style, PRETTY, com.s4e.Yoda]
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: /var/folders/6r/kv5jgb8x7vg0zjsm7txslw4m0000gp/T/gwt-codeserver-3510568745067092582.tmp
   Loading inherited module 'com.s4e.Yoda'
      [WARN] Line 47: Setting configuration property named 'CssResource.legacy' in module 'com.s4e.Yoda' that has not been previously defined
2021-11-05 09:42:39.169:INFO::main: Logging initialized @4843ms
   Loading Java files in com.s4e.Yoda.
   Module setup completed in 5997 ms
2021-11-05 09:42:42.006:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.14.v20151106
2021-11-05 09:42:42.044:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@13cbc3a0{/,null,AVAILABLE}

The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
Code server started in 6.353 s ms
[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl
2021-11-05 09:42:42.079:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@53cd0ec5{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:9876}
2021-11-05 09:42:42.079:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @7753ms
Dev Mode initialized
```

When I open the url http://127.0.0.1:9876/ I get a message Can't find any GWT Modules on this page. when I click on the button **Dev Mode On**.

I am missing something but I don't know what, it seems the javascript is not build, I don't know if I miss an option to start another server or something to build the javascript and start the web server ?

EDIT 1:

Ok so I can access http://127.0.0.1:9876/MY_MODULE/ and http://127.0.0.1:8080/MY_MODULE/ but when I use the bookmark Dev mode on on the page  http://127.0.0.1:8080/MY_MODULE/ I still have the message **Can't find any GWT Modules on this page**.

I check the javascript it seems, the js variable __gwt_activeModules in dev_mode_on.js is empty I don't know what I am missing here.

EDIT 2:

The entry point of the gwt app is a jsp file maybe this is why it doesn't work ?

In this file I have : the script MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.nocache.js

When I open the url : http://127.0.0.1:8080/MY_MODULE/ I don't see any html/jsp file

Comment: I think the warning ‘[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl’ should be heeded here.

Comment: startupUrl just open a url when the server is ready, I already tried

Comment: with SDM you don't go to the codeserver (on port 9876) in your browser.  You go to the URL of your webapp's entry page which you are running in your own Jetty.  So, can you even bring up your entry page?  e.g. myapp.html ?

Comment: Yes I know that, 9876 is the compilation server, 8080 the webserver, the thing is I don't have an html entry point, my entry point is a jsp file. When I go to 127.0.0.1:8080 I don't see any html/jsp file, I only have css and js file (MY_MODULE.nocache.js), I tried to use the url 127.0.0.1:8080/index.jsp but I have a 404 not found where index.jsp is a file defined in the web.xml file under <welcome-file-list>, I thing this is the problem because I can't execute any js file because I don't have any entry point

Comment: At this stage, this isn't a GWT problem, it's a more fundamental problem with the web app or the way you are running it in Jetty.  Can you try using a index.html file, and add the usual <script> tag to source your GWT *.nocache.js file ?

Comment: and depending on how you configure tomcat or jetty, the url path might be /index.html or it might be /mywebapp/index.html

Comment: Yeah I think my problem is the way i start my Jetty, it seems logic because I don't have any (html,jsp) entry point on 8080, I will try another way thx

Comment: is the index.jsp located inside the webapp folder?

Comment: No I think the app is not load in a good way in my jetty thx all I know what to do.